# How to track Registration form fields with Custom Variables in GA

Tags: google-analytics

I have a registration form with default fields and one drop down with 5 values say 1 - 5 And this field is mandetory.

How could i track this values thorugh Custom Variables for successful registered users?

What would be the other options if we cont track this through CV's?

Answer (score 0):

Custom variables are pretty much a thing of the past - Universal Analytics has custom dimensions which are conceptually different and are not very well suited to store form input. Plus there is the danger that the form contains info that can be used to identify a person, and it's against Googles Terms of Service to store that in Google Analytics.

One possible way to solve this would be to create a Spreadsheet on Google Drive and publish it as a webapp to store the form data along with an anonymized ID per user; the same user id would be set as a session based custom dimension in Google Analytics. Using the Google Analytics Spreadsheet add-on or a bit of bespoke Google Apps Script you could then pull the relevant metrics per id into the spreadsheet to create your reports.